# Get orders API does not include custom extension attributes

Tags: magento2, orders, extension-attributes

The reason is in the [documentation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Api/OrderRepositoryInterface.php) itself: `This call returns an array of objects, but detailed information about each object’s attributes might not be included.`

What I'm looking for is something **to force** the inclusion of this custom attribute into the extension attributes response object.

This is how I created the custom attribute:

1) Added the attribute in the database with the standard way in */Setup/UpgradeData*.

2) `etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
    <attribute code="myCustomAttr" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

3) Two observer events: `sales_order_save_before` and `sales_order_load_after`

One of the observers:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderLoadAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
      $order = $observer->getOrder();
      $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();

      if ($extensionAttributes === null) {
          $extensionAttributes = $this->getOrderExtensionDependency();
      }

      $attr = $order->getData('myCustomAttr');
      $extensionAttributes->setData('myCustomAttr', $attr);
      $order->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
  }

  private function getOrderExtensionDependency()
  {
      $orderExtension = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
          '\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension'
      );
      return $orderExtension;
  }
}
```

This works, the custom attribute is correctly loaded into the `extension attributes` of the `GET /order/{id}` REST API and saved with the PUT.

The GetOrdersList service (*/orders?searchCriteria=etc.)* is the only one which does not return the attribute. Any idea?

Comment: For now, I had to create a custom REST service with the same functionalities

Comment: Please try to use Plugin for Order Repository. Your plugin should have functions like "afterGetList","afterGet" where you can set Extension Attributes. Please See  reference https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html