# How to add extension attributes to order interface in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, rest-api, order-details

I wanted to write custom rest api to get all customer's order and details using customer token. I'm able to achieve this by this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/227141/71939).

But it is not loading up my custom extension attribute (Delivery Slot) in the order details api.

Also I need to load the image/thumnail url for each product/item in that order.

Can anyone help me out in this regard?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242565/get-orders-api-does-not-include-custom-extension-attributes

Comment: this will helkp you

Answer (score 3):

Please check the below links :

1. https://store.fooman.co.nz/blog/an-introduction-to-extension-attributes.html
2. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add extension attributes in Magento 2 Order data by creating a**extension_attributes.xml** file under etc folder.

Get insight into extension attributes in Magento 2 by referring blog,

[Magento 2 Order Extension Attribute](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/extension-attribute-in-order-data-magento-2/)

add code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="order_comment" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Comment: is there any way to use extension attribute in search criteria for order API? I have created extension attribute which is column in separate table. Everything is working fine but when you try use it in the search criteria for the order i get column not found issue. It is looking in sales_order table but my attribute is a field in custom table. How can i use extension attribute for API search? Please let me know if you know something on this.